# Professor Annity’s invention

Tags: wordplay, word-property

The following morning, I found my mentor, Professor Annity, busily cleaning up after what looked like a series of curious experiments.  As I entered the lab, she fixed me with a familiar sort of excited, faintly frenzied expression, and ushered me across to the workbench, upon which lay five similar-looking bundles, each slightly different in shape, each covered over with a cloth.

“Well! I may have worked all night, but... as you will learn, success comes with perseverance. Behold, my latest invention!” She gestured to the fifth bundle.  “Ah! But before I unveil it, let us first examine failed experiments #1 - #4, the better for you to understand my processes.”

Fighting back my natural curiosity I nodded assent, and the good Professor indicated the first bundle.  I peeked beneath the cloth.  “This one, frankly, was a mistake... The second, well, as you can see - it’s even less interesting.  Moving quickly on...”  She picked up the third bundle and handed it to me.  “This one is lighter than the others.”  I nodded again - indeed, it did appear lighter.  I replaced it on the bench.  “So far, though - unremarkable.  Experiment #4 though, I think you’ll agree, was an astonishing attempt!”

And indeed, dazzled though I was by the Professor’s ingenuity, as she made to lift the fifth veil and reveal her newest invention, I interrupted with a splutter. “Excuse me, Professor.  I believe I may have deduced what it is you have created...”

**What was the Professor's invention?**

Hint 1:

> The five taken together form, not a sequence, but a complete set.

Comment: Could we get a hint?

Comment: I had an idea that it would be the 5 words you can't say on television, but it turned out to be 7, so no.  But the clue "Prof Annity"  might help someone.

Comment: Hmm... I got an idea! Professor Annity, Prof Annity, Profanity... That is it! I found a clue! (Sadly, only a partial).

Answer (score 10):

I think the Professor's Invention is a

> BLENDER

Other inventions

#1 - "a mistake"

> BL**U**NDER

#2 - "even less interesting"

> BL**A**NDER

#3 - "lighter than the others"

> BL**O**NDER

#4 - "an astonishing attempt!"

> BL**I**NDER

So clearly the one that completes the set is

> BL**E**NDER

Comment: I have stared at this one for years and never been able to work this one out - great job! Can I ask what finally cracked it for you - what was the lightning bolt moment?

Comment: @Stiv you know, it's funny, I hadn't looked at this in ages (but did many times after it was posted) but the answer below raised a flag in my inbox because I follow the question.  So I decided to read it again and something about the hint suggested the pattern to me (group of five, not in sequence) so I looked up synonyms for "mistake" and tried to mess around with replacements there. Weirdly, the Prof Annity bit is probably what threw me off before but I think it's just a funny quirk rather than a clue.